# $s$-isotopy of braids is an equivalence relaiton

Tags: general-topology, low-dimensional-topology, braid-groups

So, I have been reading Chapter 6 of *"A Study of Braids"* by Murasugi and Kurpita. The main goal of the chapter is to prove that many notions of equivalence of braids actually coincide. I have had issues with various arguments made by the authors; in particular, I can't see how one of the notions of equivalence is actually an equivalence relation on the set of $n$-braids (the proof of this fact is given as an exercise).

To be more specific, the authors define a *braid (ambient) isotopy* as follows:

[image]

Moreover, $H$ is said to be a *$s$-isotopy* if the following property is also satisfied:

[image]

and in this case $\beta$ and $\beta'$ are said *$s$-isotopic*.

First of all, I assume there is a typo in this sentence, once "$h_t$ is always an $n$-braid" makes no sense. Instead, I interpreted the property as "$h_t(\beta)$ is always an $n$-braid", as it seems to be the most appropriate alternative.

However, I can't see how one proves that the relation of $s$-isotopy of braids is symmetric and transitive. For example, if $\beta$ and $\beta'$ are $s$-isotopic via $H$, the natural candidate for an $s$-isotopy between $\beta'$ and $\beta$ would be $H^{-1}$ (which works just fine for the case of a simple isotopy). But $(3)$ only guarantees that $h_t(\beta)$ is a braid, which, at an arbitrary instant $t$, need not have anything to do with $\beta'$, making it hard to prove $(3)$ for $H^{-1}$.

To be honest, I am not even 100% sure if this is actually true (the only other place I found this concept of $s$-isotopy was Birman's book, but she doesn't give any proofs), but I would appreciate any help understanding how one could construct the $s$-isotopies we need, or how to see that it can't be done.

Comment: Homeomorphisms can be used to create an equivalence relation. This is shown in most introductory topology books. For ambient isotopy we need to ensure properties (1) and (2) also hold for each transformation between our two equivalent braids. For s-isotopy, we also need to ensure property (3) holds for each transformation between our two equivalent braids.